# jquery ui draggable start is sluggish ~ f(DOM size)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Let me first say "THE CODE DOES NOT USE DROPPABLE".  Instead, on draggable "stop" it does work to figure out what element it ended up on, and it takes action accordingly.  So the web-ubiquitous advice about "limiting the number of droppable elements" is not germane here.

The delay I'm measuring is [time from initiation of drag] to [appearance of jquery helper item]. I don't care about drag speed, which is not terrific but it doesn't matter.

On a DOM packed with tons of stuff, I can see 2-3 second delays from initiating the drag to the helper item appearing.

On a DOM packed with half that much stuff, the delay drops to 1 second.

On a DOM packed with a modest amount of stuff, there's no appreciable delay.

So the delay seems pretty linear with DOM size.

Note that I can add other objects to the fat DOM and they appear immediately. So it's not the act of "adding stuff to the DOM in general" that's slow.

Any clues RE bettering this performance would be helpful. "Throwing the 'draggable' code away and using HTML5 drag/drop" is on my list at this point, believe me.  But I'd prefer not to refactor this mess since it works very well at present except for the above nagging edge case.

Could it be doing something like iterating the whole DOM, inefficiently looking for its "droppable" friends that aren't there?

If so, is there a way to convince it that it has no friends?

This is Chrome 59.0.3071.115 (64 bit).  I don't care about making it work anywhere else, so cross-browser issues are unimportant.

**** RESOLVED. The issue is not draggable's fault.  Adding any jquery handler (via $mumble.on) takes a hideously long time on the fat DOM.

Adding a non-jquery handler takes somewhat less time, but still creates a long delay.

Adding CSS classes is also slow and creates a long delay.

The DOM is simply too large.

Comment: Hi, For the community to be able to help you, we need to see the minimum code required to replicate the issue you are experiencing.
Without that, its just a shot in the dark.
If possible, please also provide a running version of your code on one of the many available platforms like jsfiddle and the similar.

Comment: Hi, in fact I WAS looking for "just a shot in the dark", as you say.  There is no hope of replicating the massive DOM on jsfiddle or anywhere else, and as the problem statement says, the draggable code works efficiently and well when the DOM is a reasonable size. So some factor other than coding stupidity is at play; and it seemed to me to be reasonable to poll the community to see if our experience tickled any memories of analogous situations.